# Azure Function moved in to network security group gets empty

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kudu, network-security-groups

We are applying network segmentation in some of our azure environments so I have moved my azure functions into a subnet and a network security groups with some restrictions. After this some of my functions that was deployed before gets empty and when I try to redeploy them i get the error below.

When i access the *.scm.azurewebsites.net-site the "Debug Console -page" with the usual directory tree is empty as can be seen in the attached image.

The error does not get away by removing the network security group/subnet so something seems broken in my function. Any idea on how to find the problem?

Might be a coincidence but in two environments both my time-triggered functions stopped working and not the blob-triggered ones.

```
2019-07-02T11:31:55.0820181Z ##[error]Error: Error: (2019-07-02 13:31:54) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: Access to the path 'D:\home\' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectoriesFromRoot(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddAppOfflineFilesToEachApp(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.Add(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)
```

[image: picture of scm window]

Comment: Did you have any network restrictions? Or did you set any settings in the configurations?

Comment: I added some inbound rules to the network security group. I allowed Azure Load Balancer and connections from my other network security groups (web/api/function). The outbound rules I leaved unmodified.The subnet where my function is running has access to "Service endpoint" "Microsoft.Storage". I dont have any other restrictions, and my other functions that do work "lives" in the same network security group and subnet. Removing the restrictions and association with the subnet/network security groups does not restore the function.

Comment: I ended up recreating the functions and it solved my problem.